# generic handler works in visual studio 2010 but not on iis7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, generic-handler

I've written a generic handler that intercepts requests for an image and the permits or denies based on the users credentials and the image location.  It works great in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

When I deploy to W2K2008R2 IIS7.5 in integrated pipeline mode, the generic handler does not fire.

I've tried moving the ashx file.

I've followed the instructions for migrating from cassini to IIS7.5 (properly placing the configuraiton in system.webservers vs. system.web)

Anyone have any ideas of what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

If you author an HTTP handler in .NET and wish it works for all incoming requests on IIS 7.5, you need to use integrated pipeline mode, and set required parameters,

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline/